# Store dates chosen from MonthCalendar in array

Tags: vb.net

Is it possible to use the `MonthCalendar` to select and bold non contiguous dates and later store them in a SQL table?

I have tried a third part month calendar from here(codeproject.com/Articles/10840/Another-Month-Calendar). I can select multiple dates by using the Ctrl key. The writer has given the following code :

```
  Private Sub monthCalendar2_DaySelected(sender As Object, e As    
  Pabo.Calendar.DaySelectedEventArgs) 
      ' Using the days from the EventArgs   
         m_daysSelected = e.Days 
       ' Using SelectedDates
          m_dates =   MonthCalendar2.SelectedDates
   End Sub.
```

However,I do not know how to use it to store the selected dates in my Sql table. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you can. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.monthcalendar(v=vs.110).aspx shows the process of adding to the BoldedDates collection. So presumably you can add to it in the Date_Selected event. And it's possible to store dates in SQL, so there's a potential solution. Good luck.

Comment: It will flicker like a cheap motel, not very intuitive to use either.  A ListBox and an Add and Remove button is sensible.

Comment: I have tried a third part month calendar from here(http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10840/Another-Month-Calendar).  I can select multiple dates by using the Ctrl key. The writer has given the following code :          Private Sub monthCalendar2_DaySelected(sender As Object, e As Pabo.Calendar.DaySelectedEventArgs)
        ' Using the days from the EventArgs
        m_daysSelected = e.Days
        ' Using SelectedDates
        m_dates = MonthCalendar2.SelectedDates

    End Sub. HoweverI do not know how to use it to store the selected dates in my Sql table

Comment: have you set up a sql database? Which database vendor is it? Have you researched into how to store items in a SQL database? The principles are essentially the same regardless of whether the items are dates or any other type. I suggest you make an attempt using your chosen DB platform and then edit the question when you encounter a problem - people are unlikely to write the entire thing for you, it's a fairly standard operation that you can understand from following existing tutorials.